# with python, how can i convert a txt file on windows to a unix type?

Tags: python, linux

often times, i forget to change the document type(?) to unix, instead of windows before loading to a linux environment.

when i run the file from there, i get:

```
filename.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
```

is there a way to change the text file from python?

ideally, through a sub process on the command line or something that doesn't require me to open the file and add EOL stuff?

otherwise, is there a way to build that into a return from the subprocess?

because if i do `$?` i get `0` after running a text that is not formatted correctly.

edit:

something weird is happening - i was originally testing this out in linux and was getting that 'error'.  when i run `plink` on a the same file, it actually reads it like unix and runs it correctly...

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://superuser.com/questions/71507/convert-unix-line-endings-to-windows

Comment: It's easier just to use [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) command.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the `newline` parameter of `open`.  By default `open` uses *universal newline* when text mode is used, and converts all new line types (\r, \n, \r\n) to \n.  Read the whole file in, then write it out again with a specified `newline`:

Example (overwrites original file!):

```py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:  # default is 'rt' read text mode.
    data = f.read()

with open(sys.argv[1], 'w', newline='\n') as f: # write with Unix new lines.
    f.write(data)
```

Also, without `newline` specified it will use the platform default, so on Windows it will write \r\n endings, and on Unix it will write \n endings if you leave the parameter out.